# how to set up localhost to your domain name?

Tags: localhost, ip-address, mamp, domain-name

I have created web page using following program: html,css and php, in mamp plate form. Now i don't not know how to connect the web page created on mamp to my domain. I have tried the following youtube video to set up my domain to local host, but I am not successful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3COv1kjGT1c&t=210s&list=PL7BJ9Egki0pkOHkuthi7lCEDXSCXB_hK8&index=8.

It there anything i should do on the website i bought my domain? like connecting my domain to ip address? like the following web page?

https://support.aiso.net/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/240/2/how-do-i-add-my-domain-name-to-my-computers-host-file

I have tried for many day with no success. please any help would be much appreciated.

sincerely,
siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your local computer ip? If you do not know post a screenshot of running the command `ipconfig` in command prompt. This is assuming you are using windows. Then go to your router port forwarding and forward that ip out. Then go to your domain host and forward your domain to the ip the following website shows. https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip&oq=what+is+my+ip&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2008j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Please let me know if you need help with port forwading, dns, etc. I need more info to give you exact info. If you want eexact instrctions please give me your router ip, model number, operating system, and your computer ip.

Good luck!

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I did the first part, which include find ip and forwarding it to my domain. It still not working. I created this web page from scratch using html, php and css. then I downloaded MAMP, which is a mac based plated form for running your webpage. Now i could opent my webpage through MAMP, but i want it to be connected to my domain name i bought from godaddy. I was able to connect my local host to ip and forwared to domain name, but it still not working. do i need to do port forwading, dns and etc?